# Trying to annualize salary in dataset. It comes in hourly, weekly, monthly and annual

Tags: python

```
def annual_rate(x):
    if x["unit_of_wage"] == "Hour":
        return df["prevailing_wage"] * 40 * 52
    elif x["unit_of_wage"] == "Week":
        return df["prevailing_wage"] * 52
    elif x["unit_of_wage"] == "Month":
        return df["prevailing_wage"] * 12
    else:
        return df["prevailing_wage"]
```

df = df.assign(annual_salary_calc=df.apply(annual_rate, axis=1))

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the function in such a way where it only functions as a multiplier:

```
def annual_rate(x):
    if x["unit_of_wage"] == "Hour":
        return 40 * 52
    elif x["unit_of_wage"] == "Week":
        return 52
    elif x["unit_of_wage"] == "Month":
        return 12
    else:
        return 1
```

Then used df.assign:

```
df = df.assign(annual_salary_calc=df.apply(annual_rate, axis=1))
```

I then created a new column, to multiply the wages with my multiplier:

```
columndf["annual_wage_computed"] = df["prevailing_wage"] * df["annual_salary_calc"]
```